# dispatch_semaphore_t in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, semaphore, dispatch

I am using the below code in `objective C` to work with semaphore.

```
-(void)doSome{
    semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    BaseViewController *baseVC = [[BaseViewController alloc]init];
    if(baseVC.isUserObjectExist){
        [self callLoginWebService:baseVC.userObject.username passwordString:baseVC.userObject.password];
    }else{
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }

    while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) { //2
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:100]];
    }

}
```

But

> 'dispatch_semaphore_t' is unavailable in Swift

How to integrate semaphores in swift 3 ?

Comment: **Do not** use semaphores for such an asynchronous method call. Use a completion handler.

Comment: @vadian, I want to call a asynchronous method under the splash screen. What is better way. How can I achieve it using completion handler. Please guide.

Answer (score 7):

you can create by

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
```

[Learn official document of Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore)

OR From other code

```
let url = URL(string: "")
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0) // 1
        let _ = DownloadPhoto(url: url!) {
            _, error in
            if let error = error {
            }
            semaphore.signal() // 2
        }
        let timeout = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5)
        if semaphore.wait(timeout: timeout) == .timedOut { // 3
        }
```

Comment: You passed `value` as 0. What is its significance.

Comment: 2. In my case, the callback from `DownloadPhoto` is in main queue. So the semaphore never gets signalled. How to work with semaphores using main queue.

Comment: haha, the same question, need exactly the same in tests, and no answer for 2.5 yrs :(